# Flutter: Error with metadata in manifest when building app with --split-per-abi

Tags: android, xml, flutter, metadata

I build my app with the code:
`flutter build apk --split-per-abi --release`
I want to get rid of this:
--E- cannot write metadata in manifest, cannot found manifest file

This is how the error looks and only happens when building through split per abi
[image: This is how the error looks and only happens when building through split per abi]

I know the app still builds and works perfectly.
I want to understand what it is and how to solve it.

The manifest XML looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.voltrac.fluttermap">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application android:label="La Palma VolTrac" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```